# How to select and copy files with specific file names from one directory to another?

Tags: python, directory, shutil

I have a directory with two different types of filenames daily/monthly:

```
 report_20-10-2019.csv
 report_21-10-2019.csv
 report_22-10-2019.csv

 report_09-2019.csv
 report_10-2019.csv
 report_11-2019.csv
```

I'm trying to copy only daily files to another directory. So far I'm able to copy all the files with the below code:

```
import shutil
import os
import glob

source_daily = '/path/to/files/to/copy/*.csv'
dest1 = 'path/to/directory/where/i/paste/my/files/'

files = os.listdir(source)

for file in glob.glob(source):
shutil.copy(file, dest1);
```

Would someone be able to help with this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can certainly do that,

```
import shutil
import os
import re

source = '/path/to/files/to/copy/'
dest1 = 'path/to/directory/where/i/paste/my/files/'

for filename in os.listdir(source):
    filepath = os.path.join(source, filename)
    if os.path.isfile(filepath):
        if re.search(r"[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+\.csv", filepath):
            shutil.copy(filepath, dest1)
```

Hope it addresses your problem!

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for, thanks a mil!

Answer (score 0):

Using Regular Expressions should work for you:

```
import re

import shutil
import os
import glob

source_daily = '/path/to/files/to/copy/*.csv'
dest1 = 'path/to/directory/where/i/paste/my/files/'

files = os.listdir(source)

pattern = re.compile('\w+_[0-3]\d-[0-1]\d-\d{4}.csv') #naming-pattern

for file in glob.glob(source):
    if pattern.match(file):
        shutil.copy(file, dest1);
```